# Passing arguments to $.then function

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have something like the following:

```
$(".remove-item").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.when(removeItem(url))
      .then(removeItemResponse(id));
});

var removeItemResponse = function(data, id) {
   console.log(data);
   console.log(id);
};

var removeItem = function(url) {
  return $.post(url);
};
```

The above isn't working in that I get nothing in the logs after the ajax request is processed and I know it has something to do with how I'm addressing the arguments in removeItemResponse.  I need to use the returned data from the ajax post but also pass in the id I retrieved in the click function.

Comment: Where is `removeItem` defined?

Comment: You've shown us everything but removeItem, could you do that?

Comment: I don't think `removeItem` is relevant. Knowing how it is defined won't help with passing `id` through to the .then callback fn.

Comment: I added the removeItem function, but I don't believe it really matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`removeItemResponse(id)` is executing the function immediately, and you aren't passing the result of the first deferred. Try this instead:

```
.then(function(data) { removeItemResponse(data, id) });
```

`done()` also works here:

```
.done(function(data) { removeItemResponse(data, id) });
```

You can simplify and handle failures like so:

```
removeItem(url)
    .done(function(data) { removeItemResponse(data, id) });
    .fail(function(result) { /* do something else */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're abusing when/then, they don't apply here. Just use `.done` on the promise returned from `removeItem`. It will be passed the result of the AJAX request (assuming it's returning the promise returned by a `$.ajax` invocation or the like), and then you can pass that result and the id on to your handling function:

```
removeItem(url).done(function (data) {
  removeItemResponse(data, id);
});
```

Comment: I want a separate function to deal with non-200 status response, and it is working in that regard.  How am I "abusing" it?

Comment: when/then have a specific purpose, and this isn't it. The code you've posted can be accomplished with a single `.done`.